# Verify that $y=x^3+7$ is a solution of the differential equation $y'=3x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know this is trivial but I don't don't know if I'm right

Verify, by substitution, if the function is a solution of differential equation.

$y'=3x^2$ , $y=x^3+7$

---

Differentiating the function $y=x^3+7$ you get  $y'=3x^2$

Adding that resut to the $y'=3x^2$ I get

$3x^2+3x^2=0$

The equation can't be equaled to zero so is not a solution.

Do you know where I can find more examples like this one I have a book about differential equations but don't have examples that can help me.

Comment: If you differentiate $y=x^3+7$ you get $y'=3x^2$ is that what you mean?  I'm not sure where the equation fits into this.

Comment: @Karl yes thats what i mean

Comment: In that case the cubic appears spurious to the problem.

Comment: How did you get $3x^2+x^3+7$?

Comment: @John well i just follow an example in youtube where you just need add the result of differentiating the function to the other equation

Comment: @Karl what do you mean with spurious?

Comment: Not logical. Fake, misleading.

Comment: So in conclusion we can say that is not a solution to the equation?

Comment: Solution to what equation?  The differentiation  part has nothing to do with the cubic. You appear to have computed $y'+y $ then equated the expression with zero but I can't see why unless there is a part of the problem missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $y' = 3x^2$, and want to verify that $y_p = x^3 + 7$ is a solution to the equation.

Clearly, $y'_p = 3x^2$, so $y'_p = 3x^2 = y'$... it is a solution to the equation. In fact, $y_p = x^3 + C$ is a solution for all $C$ for the same reasoning above.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know what the differential equation you are trying to solve is.

An (ordinary) differential equation is an expression $F(x, y, y', ..., y^{(n)}) = 0$. Now if you have one of these, and they give you some function $y=f(x)$, then you can take the appropriate derivatives, and substitute in to the equation and see if it works out. This is the verification you describe.

For example, consider the equation $y'' + y = 0$. We can verify that $y = \sin (x)$ is a solution. The second derivative of $y$ is $-\sin (x) $, and so by substitution $-\sin (x) + \sin (x) = 0$, and this is a true statement. So we have verified the solution.